# Inserting a String inside a String

Tags: vb.net

I want to insert a word inside an existing word? Both are Strings.

For example:

Given String word:

```
HELLO SAMPLE SENTENCE
```

i want to insert the word `I AM A` so my output would be:

```
HELLO I AM A SAMPLE SENTENCE
```

i am inserting here basing on the word `SAMPLE`. So the insertion starts before the word `SAMPLE`. is this possible?

Comment: What logical are you criteria are you using to make this decision?

Comment: is this possible with RegEx? i am not good with RegEx but i think it has to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description of your logic (which isn't much to go on), I would use:

```
Dim input As String = "HELLO SAMPLE SENTENCE"
Dim iSample As Integer = input.IndexOf("SAMPLE")
Dim output As String = input.Insert(iSample, "I AM A ")
```

This uses the BCL function String.Insert, which simply inserts a string into another string at a particular position.

Comment: Nice. Don't hardcode a `6`, but use `input.IndexOf("SAMPLE")` instead

Comment: Thanks alot this worked. This will be added to my notes. I am still learning the basics.

Comment: @Jacob, good point, I looked around for something relating to the logic of where he wanted to insert, missed that somehow. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function like this:

```
Function InsertBefore(sentence As String, find As String, textToInsert As String
    Return sentence.Replace(find, textToInsert+Find)
End Function
```

And call it like this:

```
sentence = InsertBefore("HELLO SAMPLE SENTENCE", " SAMPLE ", "I AM A")
```

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, you can use the `String.split()` function on your string.

See [DotNetPerls'](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet) page on Split here.

You can split the string into an array, then insert the line you want into the array, then join them back together using `String.Join()` (thanks Monty, I don't use Visual Basic that frequently anymore, I forgot that :)).

Hope this help :)

Comment: You can also join using a `String.Join()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx)